# (SQL) Per ID, starting from the first row, return all successive rows with a value N greater than the prior returned row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following example dataset:

| ID | Value | Row index (for reference purposes only, does not need to exist in final output) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4 | 1 |
| a | 7 | 2 |
| a | 12 | 3 |
| a | 12 | 4 |
| a | 13 | 5 |
| b | 1 | 6 |
| b | 2 | 7 |
| b | 3 | 8 |
| b | 4 | 9 |
| b | 5 | 10 |

I would like to write a SQL script that returns the **next** row which has a Value of N or more than the previously returned row starting from the first row per ID and ordered ascending by [Value]. An example of the final table for N = 3 should look like the following:

| ID | Value | Row index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4 | 1 |
| a | 7 | 2 |
| a | 12 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 6 |
| b | 4 | 9 |

Can this script be written in a vectorised manner? Or must a loop be utilised? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  "First row" implies that you have an ordering.  What column or columns specify the ordering?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for correcting the tags. Order is by the [Value] column itself, I have edited my original post to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no definition of "previous" value, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  With such a column, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by id order by <ordering column>) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <= value - 3;
```

EDIT:

I think I misunderstood what you want to do.  You seem to want to start with the first row for each id.  Then get the next row that is 3 or higher in value.  Then hold onto that value and get the next that is 3 or higher than that.  And so on.

You can do this in SQL using a recursive CTE:

```
with ts as (
      select distinct t.id, t.value, dense_rank() over (partition by id order by value) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, value, value as grp_value, 1 as within_seqnum, seqnum
      from ts
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select ts.id, ts.value, 
             (case when ts.value >= cte.grp_value + 3 then ts.value else cte.grp_value end),
             (case when ts.value >= cte.grp_value + 3 then 1 else cte.within_seqnum + 1 end),
             ts.seqnum
      from cte join
           ts
           on ts.id = cte.id and ts.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte
where within_seqnum = 1
order by id, value;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef07161a8e02a341df388d3192ea8496) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I have considered using LAG/LEAD but the issue here is that the offset parameter for these functions has to be dynamic. With the above script as is, it does not return the correct output for ID = 'b' because the current and immediately previous row never has a difference of 3 or more.